# NSUserDefaultsから取り出した配列をlabel.textに代入したい

Tags: swift

NSUserDefaultsに格納されている配列の文字列をテーブルビューの複数のセル上のLabelに表示したいのですが、label.textに代入するところで

*Type AnyObject? has no subscript members*

というエラーがでて、ビルドできません。
オプショナル型のAnyObjectからString型に変換すればよいのだろうか、と推測したものの、具体的な方法が分からず、質問させていただきました。

```
//これだとエラーがでる
let test = ud.objectForKey("test")
cell!.label.text = test[indexPath.row]

//こちらだと正常に表示される
let test = ["A", "B", "C"]
cell!.label.text = test[indexPath.row]
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ud.objectForKey("test")`部ですが、`ud.arrayForKey("test")`ではないですか？
NSUserDefaultsから値を取り出す際には、`stringForKey`, `arrayForKey`, `dictionaryForKey`, `boolForKey`等、取り出す型を明示して取り出すメソッドが多数有ります。
その内の適切な型の`xxxForKey`を使うべきでしょう。

今回は成功例から(文字列の)配列と想像されるので、`ud.objectForKey`ではなく`ud.arrayForKey`を使うべきだと思われます。

Comment: arrayForKeyで、値が取り出せました。
非常にすばやい回答、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

> オプショナル型の`AnyObject`から`String`型に変換すればよいのだろうか、と推測したものの、

これは、「オプショナル型の`AnyObject`から`String`型**を要素とする配列**に変換」という考え方にしなければいけません。
すでに、メソッド`ud.arrayForKey("test")`を使うことで解決してますが、メソッド`ud.objectForKey("test")`のままでも、正しい結果を導くことができます。

```
if let test = ud.objectForKey("test") as? [String] {
    cell!.label.text = test[indexPath.row]
}
```

このように、`as?`（あるいは`as!`）を使って、適切な型にダウンキャストしてやれば、`objectForKey()`も使えます。

Comment: 確かに配列に格納されているオブジェクトの型まで指定するにはこちらの方が良さそうですね